# save database rows in a cookie and then retrieve them

Tags: php, cookies

i want to use PHP setcookie() and i am having a problem with it. as a matter of fact i want to fetch some rows from data base then first save them in cookies and then retrieve them. consider i have a table in my database with multiple rows and for example 4 column. how can i do this. this is my current code. any idea thank you

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
error_reporting(0);

include("config.php");

$quer= "SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." ";


$query=mysqli_query($connect,$quer)
or die(mysqli_error());
?>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
setcookie("$cookiename", $row, 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
//i do not know how can i retrieve columns now
?>

 <?php endwhile;?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can only "store" strings in cookies. Use localstore for that purpose, if you really need that...

Comment: apart from that you cannot store a cookie after all headers are sent/you had any output.

Comment: thank u for your answering could u please explain a little more or could u please make a simple code

Comment: here's a tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage

Answer (score 1):

In your case mysqli_fetch_array() function returns an multidimensional array, which means that you should refer to the $row variable, for example:

```
$row[0][0] // 1st row, 1st column
$row[2][4] // 3rd row, 5th column
```

You can also fetch data as an assotiative array, look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: hi thank you for your answering. could u please explain it a little more. and  add cookie codes to your code. thus i know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
$cookie_name="cook";
setcookie($cookie_name, $row['key'],2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), "/");
```

Check this out for more:[setcookie](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)

Comment: hi thank you for your answering. what is 'key' in your code

Comment: if array is {"name":"satty","work","stack"} then name and work are keys whose value are satty and stack respectively

Answer (score 0):

If you really want/need to save the entire row in the cookie you can pack the array $row in a single string eg as JSON:

```
//modified example from @Satty
$cookie_name="cook";
setcookie($cookie_name, json_encode($row),2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), "/");

//to read the cookie:
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
    $row_from_cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
```

If there is a certain caracter that you can be sure of that it isn't present in your data so it can be used as a separator (eg. ";") you could also use [implode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) and [explode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) to pack your entire array in a single string.

But if some of the columns are of any type that can contain any character I wouldn't do it like that since there can always be a character that you didn't expect in your data (eg. if you only store names you may assume that nobody has a semicolon in his name but it's still possible that somebody enters a semicolon in the input field).

Comment: hi thank u for your answering the reason i want to do this because i want to add "add to favorites" option in to every of my ads (i am designing  a real estate website) thus if user click on "add to favorites" the post send to a favorite page and he or she can review it ant time he wants. other wid=se i do not need to save my variables in cookie

Comment: also could u please explain your code with more details for example if u can add your code to the while loop in my code and fetch the columns. because i do not know how to do that. thank u

Comment: IMHO it would make more sense to just store the IDs of the ads that were added to favourites. If the user revisits the site you would probably generate the content anyway based on the data in your database and not on what's stored in the cookie since the text or whatever of the ad might have changed in the meantime.